# Google Analytics : sending java String of length > 100 characters to Analytics

Tags: java, android, google-analytics

I am integrating Google Analytics for my Android Application. I have looked through the samples provided @ Analytics site.

e.g. Sending long ->

```
// Build and send an Event.
t.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
    .setCategory("CATEGORY_ID")
    .setAction("ACTION")
    .setLabel("LABEL_ID")
    .setValue(1l)
    .build());
```

e.g. Sending exception within 100 character limit ->

```
// Build and send exception.
t.send(new HitBuilders.ExceptionBuilder()
    .setDescription("EXCEPTION_DESCRIPTION<100_CHARS")
    .setFatal(isFatal)
    .build());
```

I want to track few error logs by sending them to Analytics.
So is there any way of sending java String of 'length' > 100 characters to Analytics ?